# How to check if a port is available?

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm trying to build port checker myself , I did everything i could but i want to use thread inside the loop. After fetch an `IP` from my-hosts file and then i can run checker on the new thread instead of blocking the main thread.Is there anyone know how to make this happen or correct my code ?

```
import socket
import threading
import time
counting_open = []
counting_close = []
port = 25
hosts = "ip.txt"
def scan():
    with open(hosts) as e:
        p = e.read().split("\n")
    for host in p : #iwant to use this for threading into the function
        s = socket.socket()
        result = s.connect_ex((host,port))
        print('working on port > '+(str(port)))      
        if result == 0:
            counting_open.append(port)
            print((str(port))+' -> open on ' + str(host)) 
            s.close()
        else:
            counting_close.append(port)
            print((str(port))+' -> close on ' + str(host))`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it sounds to me like you want to check each port in a different thread. I did a little research into the python threading library and you should be able to simply put all the code you want to run in the new thread in a function and then start a new thread with that function as the target.

In the below example I create a function that prints "running" based arg times, in a new thread.

```
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep

def threaded_function(arg):
    for i in range(arg):
        print("running")
        sleep(1)

thread = Thread(target = threaded_function, args = (10, ))
thread.start()
thread.join()
print("thread finished...exiting")
```

A way to use this with your own code could be:

```
import socket
from threading import thread
import time
counting_open = []
counting_close = []
port = 25
hosts = "ip.txt"

def scan(host):    
        s = socket.socket()
        result = s.connect_ex((host,port))
        print('working on port > '+(str(port)))      
        if result == 0:
            counting_open.append(port)
            print((str(port))+' -> open on ' + str(host)) 
            s.close()
        else:
            counting_close.append(port)
            print((str(port))+' -> close on ' + str(host))`

with open(hosts) as e:
    p = e.read().split("\n")
for h in p:
   thread = Thread(target = scan, args = (h, )) 
   thread.start()    # Start the new thread
   thread.join()     # Wait until the thread terminates
```

Hopefully this helps. Please keep in mind that the above code has not been tested.

Comment: After Some Edits To Your Code , finally its worked for me
but the thread i think its very slow idk why but i think it's not using thread

Comment: I believe the reason for that is because `thead.join()` waits for the thread to terminate before continuing so try removing it and see if that helps. Also may I ask how big your ip.text is? If it isn't that big it may be faster to just simply run the program without multithreading.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks
It's Worked

```
import socket
import threading
import time
counting_open = []
counting_close = []
threads = []
port = 25
hosts = "ip.txt"

def scan(host):    
        s = socket.socket()
        result = s.connect_ex((host,port))
        if result == 0:
            counting_open.append(port)
            print((str(port))+' -> open on ' + str(host)) 
            s.close()
        else:
            counting_close.append(port)
            print((str(port))+' -> close on ' + str(host))

with open(hosts) as e:
    p = e.read().split("\n")
for h in p:
   thread = threading.Thread(target = scan, args = (h, )) 
   threads.append(thread)    # Wait until the thread terminates
   thread.start()    # Start the new thread
for x in threads:
    x.join()
```